# Difference betweeen Session::flash and Request::flash in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

When i used Session::flash(), then the data were available for Session::old() function, but not the old helper. But when i used Request::flash(), the data were available for old helper.

So what is the trick?

Comment: Please provide some example code snippets.

Comment: I tried something like this in controller :   Session::flash("test", "sdf");
  return View::make('auth.login');, it doesnt work for old helper, but when i tried   Request::flash();
  return View::make('auth.login'); after post, it worked.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code. Don't post code relevant to the question in the comments.